# How can I convert while(mysql_fetch_assoc($run)) to PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
while($message = mysql_fetch_assoc($run)) {
}
```

How can I convert my code to PDO ?

Thank you!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Answer (score 0):

PDO alternate is `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $data = $row."\n";
  print $data;
}
```